# ng-if condition with key value - Angular js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs

I'm testing a webapp using angularjs, my app.js is reading a `JSON` file and gets some data:

```
var category = document.getElementById('category').value;
var App = angular.module('App', []);

App.controller('control', function($scope, $http){
$http.get('../../zz-dashboard/motores/datatodo/INFO/filtros/'+category+'.json')
  .then(function(res){
    $scope.items = res.data;              
  });
});
```

I would like to show the data conditioned in the key or val value, using ng-if. For example, in this case if the key of my array is equal to "sleeves" I would like to show the value, only in that case.

```
<p ng-repeat="(key, val) in items" ng-if="key=='sleeves'">            
   {{key}} - {{val}}
</p>
```

I'm new in angularjs and I didn't found a clear answer to my question, I would apreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

Just Try

```
<p ng-repeat="item in items track by $index" ng-show="$index == 'sleeves'">            
   {{$index}} - {{item}}
</p>
```

Comment: You can't answer like this if you haven't seen his json code... This work in certain case.

Comment: This didn't work with my json, but "ng-show" did it.

Comment: How you can get $index as sleeves (string). $index is a number right.

Comment: I assumed from OP's question. He said ng-if="key=='sleeves'". I assumed that OP must has indexing as a string.

Comment: Yes, it is indexing as a string.